# Maximizing cosine similarity under linear constraints

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, linear-programming, machine-learning

Given a unit vector $d$, I would like to find a weight vector $x$, which has non-negative elements and sums up to one, such that the $Ax+b$ direction aligns with $d$ as much as possible. That is,
$$\max_x \langle\frac{Ax+b}{\|Ax+b\|},d \rangle \quad \text{s.t} \quad x\geq0, \sum_{i}x_i=1$$

where $\langle,\rangle$ is the inner product.

I think this type of problem should appear a lot, but I fail to find literature on it. Is there a way to solve this efficiently? Or is there a similar optimization formulation that can be solved efficiently, such as having a close-formed solution or a linear programming problem?

Comment: This is not a convex problem.

Comment: No it is not convex. But I feel like this belong to a solvable non-convex problem.

Comment: One can start from linear system $Ax+b=kd$, $\sum_i x_i=1$. If $k$ is positive and all $x_i \geq 0$ then solution is found. Otherwise one needs to refine solution somehow. Other way to solve problem is using non-linear optimization techniques.

Comment: I believe dividing by the norm of $Ax+b$ is not necessary (you want the directions to align, and the length of the vectors do not impact this), in which case the problem is linear.